# vb6 Mid function in php

Tags: php, laravel, vb6

I'm developing a project ,written before in vb6, using PHP.

I have variable called VLSALESITEMID as string

Then a select. (VGID)

Then

```
VLSALESITEMID=VLSALESITEMID & VGID.field("SALESITEMID").Value & ","
```

Then

```
VLSALESITEMID=Mid(VLSALESITEMID, 1, Len(VLSALESITEMID) -1).
```

I want to translate it to php, any help?

MID FUNCTION :

```
' Creates text string. 
Dim TestString As String = "Mid Function Demo" 
' Returns "Mid". 
Dim FirstWord As String = Mid(TestString, 1, 3)
' Returns "Demo". 
Dim LastWord As String = Mid(TestString, 14, 4)
' Returns "Function Demo". 
Dim MidWords As String = Mid(TestString, 5)
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

Comment: Got it, and the Len function for what? Than you

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php

Comment: ok got it too, thank you again

Comment: This is removing the last comma that was left after concatenating all of the VGID.Field values together.  I don't know PHP, but in VB6, you can also obtain the same result with the Left function (since the Mid is starting at the beginning with an index of 1): `VLSALESITEMID = Left(VLSALESITEMID, Len(VLSALESITEMID) - 1)`; if that would/could be easier in PHP.

Comment: The snippet above isn't VB6.  It smells a lot like some version of VB.Net though.

Answer (score 0):

The VB6 Mid function is very similar to PHP's [substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) function.

```
<?php
// Creates text string. 
$TestString = 'Mid Function Demo';

// Returns "Mid". 
$FirstWord = substr($TestString, 0, 3);

// Returns "Demo".
$LastWord = substr($TestString, 13, 4);

// Returns "Function Demo".
$MidWords = substr($TestString, 4);

echo
'"', $FirstWord, '"<br />', "\n",
'"', $LastWord, '"<br />', "\n",
'"', $MidWords, '"';
```

Will output:

> "Mid"
>  "Demo"
>  "Function Demo"